# Fastest way to download/cache multiple small files from Azure File Storage

Tags: performance, azure, file-transfer, azure-files, azure-storage-files

I have a VM in an Azure Cloud environment that has access to an Azure Files (an Azure FileShare). 
This Azure Files is mounted to the VM.

When performing some tests, I find that large files (e.g. 100MB) are downloaded with a speed of up to 500mbps and when I download smaller files (e.g. 100KB to 1MB) the speed drops to 5-50mbps.

Performance is key here! I have a software (in C++) that uses files on this mounted FileShare. Any recommendation about settings/blocksize/cachesize or other parameters such as concurrent downloads/streams are very welcome.

Comment: How does the software connect the FileShare? Use the mounted drive directly or use the link like `https://xxxx.file.core.windows.net/xxx`?

Comment: Yep that's how I do it currently, use the link directly //azurexxx.file.core.windows.net/..

Comment: If you're using c# and these small files are in the same directory, you can consider using [Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement).